# How to prevent SQL injection attacks using parameterized queries - Play Framework

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I inherited a Play 1.2.4 application which has just been security audited. It seems some methods are unsafe so I need to change them to use prepared statements.

One of the methods in question is this:

```
public static void surveys(int startIndex, int endIndex, boolean isAscending, String orderBy, String searchField,
                               String searchText, String filter) {
        NdgUser currentUser = NdgUser.find("byUserName", session.get("ndgUser")).first();
        NdgUser currentUserAdmin = NdgUser.find("byUserName", currentUser.userAdmin).first();

        List<Survey> surveys = null;
        String query;

        if (filter != null && filter.length() > 0) {
            query = getQuery2Filters( "available" , String.valueOf( SurveyStatusConsts.getStatusFlag( filter ) ),
                                      "ndg_user_id", String.valueOf(currentUserAdmin.getId()), false,
                                      searchField, searchText, null, isAscending );//sorting is not needed now
        }
        else {
            query = getQuery( "ndg_user_id" , String.valueOf(currentUserAdmin.getId()), false,
                              searchField, searchText, null, isAscending );//sorting is not needed now
        }

        long totalItems = 0;
        totalItems = Survey.count( query );

        if ( orderBy != null && orderBy.equals( "resultCollection" ) ) {
            surveys = Survey.find( query ).fetch();
            Collections.sort( surveys, new SurveyNdgResultCollectionComapator() );

            if ( !isAscending ) {
                Collections.reverse( surveys );
            }

            int subListEndIndex = surveys.size() <= endIndex ? surveys.size() : endIndex;
            surveys = surveys.subList( startIndex, subListEndIndex );
        } else {
            if (filter != null && filter.length() > 0) {
                query = getQuery2Filters( "available", String.valueOf( SurveyStatusConsts.getStatusFlag( filter ) ),
                                          "ndg_user_id", String.valueOf(currentUserAdmin.getId()), false,
                                          searchField, searchText, orderBy, isAscending );
            }
            else {
                query = getQuery( "ndg_user_id", String.valueOf(currentUserAdmin.getId()), false,
                                  searchField, searchText, orderBy, isAscending );
            }
            surveys = Survey.find( query ).from( startIndex ).fetch( endIndex - startIndex );

        }
        serializeSurveys(surveys, startIndex, totalItems);
    }
```

which makes use of another couple of methods to actually build the query

```
 private static String getQuery(String filterName, String filterValue, boolean isFilterString, String searchField,
                                   String searchText, String orderBy, boolean isAscending ) {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

        String statusQuery = "";
        String searchQuery = "";
        String sortingQuery = "";

        if ( filterName != null && filterName.length() > 0
          && filterValue != null && filterValue.length() > 0 ) {
            statusQuery = filterName + "=" + ( isFilterString ? ("'" + filterValue + "'") : filterValue );
        }

        if ( searchField != null && searchText != null && searchText.length() > 0 ) {
            if(searchField.equals("dateSent")) {
                searchQuery = "DATE_FORMAT(" + searchField + ", '%d/%m/%Y')" + " like '%" + searchText + "%'";
            }
            else {
                searchQuery = searchField + " like '%" + searchText + "%'";
            }
        }

        if ( orderBy != null && orderBy.length()> 0 ) {
            sortingQuery = "order by " + orderBy + ( isAscending ? " asc" : " desc" );
        }

        query.append( statusQuery )
                .append( ( statusQuery.length() > 0 && searchQuery.length() > 0 ) ? " and " : ' ' )
                   .append( searchQuery )
                      .append( ' ' )
                         .append( sortingQuery );

        return query.toString();
    }
```

and

```
private static String getQuery2Filters(String filterName, String filterValue, String filterName2,
                                           String filterValue2, boolean isFilterString, String searchField,
                                           String searchText, String orderBy, boolean isAscending ) {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

        String statusQuery = "";
        String searchQuery = "";
        String sortingQuery = "";

        if ( filterName != null && filterName.length() > 0
          && filterValue != null && filterValue.length() > 0 ) {
            statusQuery = filterName + "=" + ( isFilterString ? ("'" + filterValue + "'") : filterValue );
        }

        if ( filterName2 != null && filterName2.length() > 0
          && filterValue2 != null && filterValue2.length() > 0 ) {
            statusQuery += " and " + filterName2 + "="
                        + ( isFilterString ? ("'" + filterValue2 + "'") : filterValue2 );
        }

        if ( searchField != null && searchText != null && searchText.length() > 0 ) {
            searchQuery = searchField + " like '%" + searchText + "%'";
        }

        if ( orderBy != null && orderBy.length()> 0 ) {
            sortingQuery = "order by " + orderBy + ( isAscending ? " asc" : " desc" );
        }

        query.append( statusQuery )
                .append( ( statusQuery.length() > 0 && searchQuery.length() > 0 ) ? " and " : ' ' )
                   .append( searchQuery )
                      .append( ' ' )
                         .append( sortingQuery );

        return query.toString();
    }
```

I believe it is these auxiliary methods I need to change for basic string concatenation to something using parameters but I am a bit lost as to how actually do that. I am not very familar with either Java or Hibernate/JPA so some pointers gratefully received

Comment: Heh, it would be easier to everyone if you shortened your samples...

Comment: @biesior i thought that when i was writing it..here goes..how do you transform this `if ( filterName != null && filterName.length() > 0
          && filterValue != null && filterValue.length() > 0 ) {
            statusQuery = filterName + "=" + ( isFilterString ? ("'" + filterValue + "'") : filterValue );
        }` into something using parameters for a stored procedure